# Regex validation for Unix File

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a unix file path below.

`/tester/test/testaa.html
/testing/test.jsp
/test/abc.html
/test/testxyz.htm`

It should result the file name starts with "test" and it shud not check the folder name. the result should be as below.

`/tester/test/testaa.html
/testing/test.jsp
/test/testxyz.htm`

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
.*\/test[^\/]*$
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Not, its not working... I need to match only filename starting with 'test'

Comment: and it testes only the filename

Comment: What do you mean, like `\/list[^/]+$` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using javascript
First read your file path as string then then read the first 5 char of string if its start with test/ then skip the file dont validate if otherwise validate all other files.

```
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
var path = "/tester/test/testaa.html";
var folderpath = path.substring(1, 6);
if(folderpath == "test/")
{
   alert("skip File");
}
else
{
   alert("validate File");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: So /test/testxyz.htm won't be valid for you even though it should be...?

Comment: Thanks Anand. But I need it in Regex to simplify the code.